# Shrinkwrap modifier creates creases on object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

[image: Faces which have been extruded are flat in object and edit mode, but is deformed when rendered]

Faces which have been extruded are flat in object and edit mode, but is deformed when rendered. How can I prevent the creasing from happening when using the shrinkwrap modifier tool? Sorry for the simple question, I am new to blender and have never asked on this site before.

[image]

Comment: The big issue is that the faces of the object are big ngons (faces connecting more than four vertices). those will not deform or subdivide correctly. Instead of one big face have multiple quads.

Comment: Ah, this is something I knew and should have remembered. Thanks for pointing that out to me! @cegaton